# How to return distinct nodes asJson

Tags: cypher, redisgraph, opencypher

Using `GRAPH.QUERY mykey "MATCH (node:m000) RETURN toJson(node)"` I get the following:

```json
[
  {
    "key": "000", "containerid": "10000" // id 1
  },
  {
    "key": "001", "containerid": "10001" // id 2
  },
  {
    "key": "000", "containerid": "10000" // id 3
  }
]
```

I would like to not get the duplicate item in the results (the last item above).

I tried DISTINCT: `GRAPH.QUERY mykey "MATCH (node:m000) RETURN DISTINCT toJson(node)"` but that returns all records, presumably because the node `id` IS unique on each record (even though it isn't in the node properties that are being serialized).

Obviously I can filter the results myself but is there a way to do that in the graph command itself?

Thanks, Murray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the `id` property is unique, thus `DISTINCT` will not be able to filter out the duplicate without further manual filtering.

If you don't care about the id of the entity, you can write something like:
`GRAPH.QUERY mykey MATCH (node:m000) RETURN DISTINCT toJson(properties(node)), toJson(labels(node))`, which will filter the duplicate out.

Answer (score 1):

```
GRAPH.QUERY g "CREATE ({x:1, y:2, z:3}), ({x:1, y:2, z:3}), ({x:1, y:2, z:4})"

GRAPH.QUERY g "MATCH (a) RETURN toJSON(properties(a))"
1) 1) "toJSON(properties(a))"
2) 1) 1) "{\"x\": 1, \"y\": 2, \"z\": 3}"
   2) 1) "{\"x\": 1, \"y\": 2, \"z\": 3}"
   3) 1) "{\"x\": 1, \"y\": 2, \"z\": 4}"
```

If you need just the combinations of properties you can do the following:

```
GRAPH.QUERY g "MATCH (a) WITH distinct(properties(a)) as b return toJSON(b)"
1) 1) "toJSON(b)"
2) 1) 1) "{\"x\": 1, \"y\": 2, \"z\": 3}"
   2) 1) "{\"x\": 1, \"y\": 2, \"z\": 4}"
```

BTW, to get it as a single JSON:

```
GRAPH.QUERY g "MATCH (a) RETURN toJSON(collect(distinct properties(a)))"
1) 1) "toJSON(collect(distinct properties(a)))"
2) 1) 1) "[{\"x\": 1, \"y\": 2, \"z\": 3}, {\"x\": 1, \"y\": 2, \"z\": 4}]"
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. That helps better understand what you can do with toJson()